# RDP into Windows 2012 Essentials Server

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-home-server, windows-server-2012

I can not find a way to RDP into my Windows Essentials Server 2012, like I could to my old Home Server.  Am I missing something simple here?  When I try I get "Your Credentials Did Not Work", even though I'm sure I'm using the correct username & password.

Comment: encryption level? clocks in synch?

Comment: The clocks are the same, I'm not sure how to check encryption level.

Comment: Select Allow Connections From Computers Running Any Version Of Remote Desktop to allow connections from any version of Windows.
Select Allow Connections Only From Computers Running Remote Desktop With Network Level Authentication to allow connections only from Windows 7 or later computers (and computers with secure network authentication).